# Magento: Which file detects local.xml?

Tags: svn, magento, permissions

I am migrating Magento from one server to another.
I created `local.xml` file but Magento keeps redirecting to install page.

I'm also having some owner/group issues from doing SVN checkout so I suspect Magento can't read `local.xml`.

Question: Which file/part of the script, performs the detection of `local.xml`, so I can simulate whether from that same environment `local.xml` is accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely addressing your permissions issues is key here. All files should be owned by the same user that the PHP instance runs as with rwx.

You could test temporarily by:

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/my/magento/store/*
```

Also be sure to flush the following directories as a matter of course when migrating a store:

```
./var/cache/*
./var/session/*
```

To answer your question, local.xml is read in ./app/Mage.php around line +640 in the following function:

```
public static function isInstalled($options = array())
{
    if (self::$_isInstalled === null) {
        self::setRoot();

        if (is_string($options)) {
            $options = array('etc_dir' => $options);
        }
        $etcDir = 'etc';
        if (!empty($options['etc_dir'])) {
            $etcDir = $options['etc_dir'];
        }
        $localConfigFile = self::getRoot() . DS . $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';

        self::$_isInstalled = false;

        if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
            $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
                self::$_isInstalled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return self::$_isInstalled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sonassi. I found the problem. `simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);` is returning false.
Simplexml module is also loaded on my server. Can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create any separate "`local.xml`" file for the new server. Copy the old "`local.xml`" to the new web server, and edit that file to change these following variables to the new web server's values:-

- `host` // New Database Host Name, like "`localhost`" or some other values as provided to you for the new Web Server's Database
- `username` // New Database Username
- `password` // New Database Password
- `dbname` // New Database Name

After changing the values in the "`local.xml`" file for the above-mentioned nodes, save it.

Also delete the full "`var`" folder, and then start using the new Web Server for the migrated Magento.

Hope it helps.